# adding content without delete original content in XML java

Tags: java, xml, dom, transformer-model

I want to add new content inside a XML file, without delete the original content. How can I do that.

Original XML:

```
<collection>
<data>
<type>CHD</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOGICALCARDID">0000000</entry>
<entry key="PRIMARYKEYVALUE">001490499026060000000</entry>
<entry key="PRIMARYKEYOFFSET">53</entry>
</values></data>
<data>
<type>RECORD</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOGICALCARDID">0000000</entry>
<entry key="MAP_DP_EMV_SR">DDA_411</entry>
<entry key="MAP_SK_SVC_PERSO_SR">9864591</entry>
<entry key="MAP_DP_GRAPH_SR">GRAPH_PROFILE_1</entry>
</values></data>
<data>
<type>LOTPACK</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOT_PACK_GROUP">1</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_ID">GRP001</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_INDEX">1</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_QTY">3</entry>
<entry key="LOTPACKTYPE">64</entry>
</values></data>
</collection>
```

Java:

```
public class program {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String xmlFile = "order.xml";
        String xmlFile2 = "order2.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        Node LOGICALCARDID = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry").item(0);
        Node PRIMARYKEYVALUE = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry").item(1);
        Node LOGICALCARDID1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry").item(3);

        for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++){
            String number = Integer.toString(i);
            int length = number.length();
            if(length == 1){
                String digit = "000000"+number;
                LOGICALCARDID.setTextContent(digit);
                PRIMARYKEYVALUE.setTextContent("00149049902606"+digit);
                LOGICALCARDID1.setTextContent(digit);
            }else if (length == 2){
                String digit = "00000"+number;
                LOGICALCARDID.setTextContent(digit);
                PRIMARYKEYVALUE.setTextContent("00149049902606"+digit);
                LOGICALCARDID1.setTextContent(digit);
            }else if (length == 3){
                String digit = "0000"+number;
                LOGICALCARDID.setTextContent(digit);
                PRIMARYKEYVALUE.setTextContent("00149049902606"+digit);
                LOGICALCARDID1.setTextContent(digit);
            }else if (length == 4){
                String digit = "000"+number;
                LOGICALCARDID.setTextContent(digit);
                PRIMARYKEYVALUE.setTextContent("00149049902606"+digit);
                LOGICALCARDID1.setTextContent(digit);
            }

        }
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("order2.xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);

}catch (SAXParseException err) {
        System.out.println("** Parsing error" + ", line "
                + err.getLineNumber() + ", uri " + err.getSystemId());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Exception x = e.getException();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Expected XML:

```
<collection>
<data>
<type>CHD</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOGICALCARDID">0000000</entry>
<entry key="PRIMARYKEYVALUE">001490499026060000000</entry>
<entry key="PRIMARYKEYOFFSET">53</entry>
</values></data>
<data>
<type>RECORD</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOGICALCARDID">0000000</entry>
<entry key="MAP_DP_EMV_SR">DDA_411</entry>
<entry key="MAP_SK_SVC_PERSO_SR">9864591</entry>
<entry key="MAP_DP_GRAPH_SR">GRAPH_PROFILE_1</entry>
</values></data>
<data>
<type>LOTPACK</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOT_PACK_GROUP">1</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_ID">GRP001</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_INDEX">1</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_QTY">3</entry>
<entry key="LOTPACKTYPE">64</entry>
</values></data>
</collection>

<collection>
<data>
<type>CHD</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOGICALCARDID">0000001</entry>
<entry key="PRIMARYKEYVALUE">001490499026060000001</entry>
<entry key="PRIMARYKEYOFFSET">53</entry>
</values></data>
<data>
<type>RECORD</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOGICALCARDID">0000001</entry>
<entry key="MAP_DP_EMV_SR">DDA_411</entry>
<entry key="MAP_SK_SVC_PERSO_SR">9864591</entry>
<entry key="MAP_DP_GRAPH_SR">GRAPH_PROFILE_1</entry>
</values></data>
<data>
<type>LOTPACK</type>
<values>
<entry key="LOT_PACK_GROUP">1</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_ID">GRP001</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_INDEX">1</entry>
<entry key="GROUP_QTY">3</entry>
<entry key="LOTPACKTYPE">64</entry>
</values></data>
</collection>
```

Until 0000019.. But I dont know how to add the XML without delete original content. Anyone can please help me?

Comment: Your code is using DOM, but you had it tagged with jdom (which I am the maintainer of). I took the liberty of retagging it for you. On the other hand, you may be interested in uising JDOM because the type of operation yu are trying to do is (depending on your preferences) simpler than the DOM way.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Get the root element

```
Node Collection = doc.getElementsByTagName("Collection").item(0);
```

**2)** Create other elements

```
Node data = doc.createElement("data");

Node type = doc.createElement("type");

Node values = doc.createElement("values");
```

Repeat these for remaining elements

**3)** Then append child element to its immediate parent element.

```
Collection.appendChild(data)

data.appendChild("type");

type.appendChild("values");
```

Repeat these for remaining child elements